# Is AMQP's DistributionMode analogous to autoacknowledge in Tibco?

Tags: amqp, activemq-artemis

We are migrating from Tibco to start using ActiveMQ Artemis. There are several ack settings that are available on Tibco, but we haven't found anything that's simply similar to this in Artemis. We are using the amqpnetlite .NET library to interface with Artemis, and as part of our code using `DistributionMode` to either move or copy based on the boolean value we are assigning to a configuration flag that we are calling as `UseAutoAcknowledge`. I haven't found much documentation about `DistributionMode` but for one that isn't very clear here - http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/amqp-core-messaging-v1.0.html.

My question is if `DistributionMode` is set to move - does Artemis send an acknowledgement to the client and doesn't when it is set to copy?

Answer (score 1):

I can't talk to Tibco but I can try to explain AMQP `DistributionMode`.  Essentially the `DistributionMode` is a setting as to the behaviour of the receiver - a receiver with a `move` mode is expecting the messages to be sent only to it, not to other receivers - this is the normal behaviour of a consumer on a queue. A receiver with a `copy` mode is expecting other receivers to also receive the message (like a queue browser, or - sort of - like a subscriber to a topic).  In a traditional Client-Broker topology, the DistributionMode is only really interesting when receiving messages from the Broker, and is unlikely to have effect when sending messages to the Broker.

Acknowledgement is separate from the DistributionMode.  AMQP has the concept of `Disposition` which is similar to but not the same as Acknowledgement. Disposition is ultimately the action that the sender will apply at the completion of the message transfer (and so interacts with `DistributionMode` for messages sent by the Broker).  Conceptually for each message transfer a Broker might decide that the transfer has completed successfully; that it has failed - but in a way that retrying might succeed; that it has failed in a way that will not succeed on retry; or some other more subtle outcome.  Here the behaviour at the Broker is probably different depending upon whether the `DistributionMode` was `move` or `copy` (the specification left this vague to allow flexibility in implementations).  If the receiver is asking for messages to be moved, and it declares that the transfer was unsuccessful, a broker is likely to make that message available for all competing consumers.  If the receiver was asking for copy, then it never held an exclusive lock on the message, and so the choice is only whether to retry sending the copy to that same consumer.

Perhaps the simplest thing here is if you can describe the behaviour that you desire, and experts on Apache Artemis can weigh in on if/how that can be achieved.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation Rob Godfrey! So what we are trying to understand is how we can manage the Acknowledgement of messages from Artemis. Once the messages are delivered or failed to deliver from the broker to the receiver, Is there a way for us to set something to basically auto acknowledge the message or ignore the acknowledgement altogether? This is likely causing performance issues for us in Production. Thanks again for taking time to answer my questions!